# Resizing table with shell and aligning buttons?

Tags: java, eclipse, button, swt

Can someone tell me how to resize my table if I drag shell's border. In other words I want my tables end to be connected to the shell, so that if shell is being resize, table follows. Also I have problem with button's. I need them to be positioned in bottom right corner, beneath the table, but what ever I set for alignment (GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING or new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.END, false, false) or new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.BOTTOM, false, false) it's all the same as output) it sets two of my buttons to the bottom left and one to the bottom right. Here is code and pics of table:

```
try {
        display = new Display();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    shell.setLayout(layout);

    Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    // Create a composite to hold the children
    GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL | GridData.FILL_BOTH);
    composite.setLayoutData(gridData);

    // Set numColumns to 3 for the buttons
    GridLayout layout1 = new GridLayout(3, false);
    layout1.marginWidth = 4;
    composite.setLayout(layout1);

    int style = SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | 
            SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.HIDE_SELECTION;
    final int NUMBER_COLUMNS = 6;
    table = new Table(composite, style);

    GridData gridData1 = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
    gridData1.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
    gridData1.horizontalSpan = 3;
    table.setLayoutData(gridData1);

    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);

    String[] titles = { methodHeader, messageHeader, parametersHeader, resultHeader, deltaHeader, assertionHeader};
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT, i);
        column.setText(titles[i]);
        table.getColumn(i).pack();
    }


    addDataToTableModel(methodList);

    GridData gridData2 = new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.END, false, false);
    gridData2.widthHint = 80;

    buttonOk = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
    buttonOk.setText(ok);
    buttonOk.setLayoutData(gridData2);

    buttonCancel = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
    buttonCancel.setText(cancel);
    /*GridData gridData3 = new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.END, false, false);
    gridData3.widthHint = 80;*/
    buttonCancel.setLayoutData(gridData2);

    buttonHelp = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
    buttonHelp.setText(help);
    /*GridData gridData4 = new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.END, false, false);
    gridData4.widthHint = 80;*/
    buttonHelp.setLayoutData(gridData2);
```

[image: This is how my frame looks when I run this code] 2 buttons left, 1 right.

EDIT1:
Tried using different GridData for every button:

```
    GridData gridData2 = new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.END, false, false);
    gridData2.widthHint = 80;

    buttonOk = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
    buttonOk.setText(ok);
    buttonOk.setLayoutData(gridData2);

    buttonCancel = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
    buttonCancel.setText(cancel);
    GridData gridData3 = new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.END, false, false);
    gridData3.widthHint = 80;
    buttonCancel.setLayoutData(gridData3);

    buttonHelp = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
    buttonHelp.setText(help);
    GridData gridData4 = new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.END, false, false);
    gridData4.widthHint = 80;
    buttonHelp.setLayoutData(gridData4);
```

Same result for buttons.

Comment: Don't reuse `GridData` for multiple controls - this does **not** work. You need a new `GridData` for every control.

Comment: Yes I tried that two, same result :(

Comment: I didn't say it would fix the problem, I said it is bad code.

Comment: Ok, thanks than, I didn't get that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 4 columns for the layout:

```
final GridLayout layout1 = new GridLayout(4, false);
```

and use an empty filler label to grab the space to the left of the buttons:

```
Label filler = new Label(composite, SWT.LEAD);
filler.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));

GridData gridData2 = new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.END, false, false);
gridData2.widthHint = 80;

Button buttonOk = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
buttonOk.setText("OK");
buttonOk.setLayoutData(gridData2);

gridData2 = new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.END, false, false);
gridData2.widthHint = 80;

Button buttonCancel = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
buttonCancel.setText("Cancel");
buttonCancel.setLayoutData(gridData2);

gridData2 = new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.END, false, false);
gridData2.widthHint = 80;

Button buttonHelp = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
buttonHelp.setText("Help");
buttonHelp.setLayoutData(gridData2);
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem with buttons, now I have left one more, how to delete last column (blank space) and make table resize if resizing shell?

Comment: The table does resize when resizing the shell - do you mean resizing the columns? I don't know how you would do that with just Table as I always use the JFace TableViewer.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, I used swing before and columns resized with frame. Also if I use TableViewer, can I edit cells?

Comment: Ok, so can you give me some link for editing these empty cells from my table, and getting it's content row by row after button Ok is clicked, cause I can't find any similar example.